# How to get the TTL of multiple Redis keys from C# StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, caching, redis, lua, stackexchange.redis

Trying to make up a function that takes a list of redis keys, and outputs a list of timespans for the time to live (TTL) of the keys. I'm not familiar with Lua Scripting though. I've tried following other guides online for this, but am unable to get something to work for this situation. Any insight would be super helpful and very reusable.

```
        public async Task<TimeSpan?[]> GetTTLManyAsync(string[] keySet)
        {
            try
            {
                var db = await this.GetDatabaseAsync();
                string script = @"...";
...
                var keysCasted = keySet.Select(k => new RedisKey(k)).ToArray();
                var result = await db.ScriptEvaluateAsync(script, keysCasted);
...
                return ...[array of timespans];
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteLogException(e);
                return null;
            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough solution I worked out.

```
    public async Task<List<TimeSpan?>> GetTTLManyAsync(IEnumerable<string> keys)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            var db = await this.GetDatabaseAsync();
            string script = @"local result = {}
            for i,key in ipairs(KEYS) do 
                local ttl = tonumber(redis.call('ttl', key))
                    result[i] = ttl
            end
            return result";

            var result = await db.ScriptEvaluateAsync(script, keys.Select(k => new RedisKey(k)).ToArray());
            var arrResult = ((double[])result).Select(ttl =>
            {
                if (ttl == -2) return default(TimeSpan?); // Key does not exist
                else if (ttl == -1) return default(TimeSpan?); // No expiration set.
                else return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ttl);
            }).ToList();

            return arrResult;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteLogException(e);
        }

        // Fill w/ empty values
        return new List<TimeSpan?>(new TimeSpan?[keys.Count()]);
    }
```